# PHP: extract values from array of multiple stdclass objects using loop

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

```
        `array(2) {
  ["result"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
    ["totalResults"]=>
    int(10514658)
    ["products"]=>
    array(20) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#7 (13) {
        ["lotNum"]=>
        int(1)
        ["packageType"]=>
        string(5) "piece"
        ["imageUrl"]=>
        string(141) "http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1v_x3LpXXXXbDXFXXq6xXFXXXs/Medium-Super-color-Lace-up-Zapato-Mujer-grid-print-font-b-Shoes-b-font-The-Trend.jpg"
        ["30daysCommission"]=>
        string(8) "US $0.02"
        ["productId"]=>
        float(32515275585)
        ["discount"]=>
        string(2) "0%"
        ["originalPrice"]=>
        string(9) "US $41.99"
        ["productUrl"]=>
        string(48) "http://www.aliexpress.com/item//32515275585.html"
        ["productTitle"]=>
        string(128) "Medium, Super color Lace-up Zapato Mujer grid print Shoes The Trend of Female Soft Leisure Sapatos chaussure femme winter basket"
        ["validTime"]=>
        string(10) "2016-04-15"
        ["volume"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["evaluateScore"]=>
        string(3) "5.0"
        ["salePrice"]=>
        string(9) "US $41.99"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#8 (13) {
        ["lotNum"]=>
        int(1)
        ["packageType"]=>
        string(5) "piece"
        ["imageUrl"]=>
        string(134) "http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Llk.IpXXXXasXpXXq6xXFXXXH/All-match-Women-font-b-shoes-b-font-high-canvas-font-b-shoes-b-font-women.jpg"
        ["30daysCommission"]=>
        string(8) "US $0.39"
        ["productId"]=>
        int(944204198)
        ["discount"]=>
        string(2) "0%"
        ["originalPrice"]=>
        string(9) "US $32.40"
        ["productUrl"]=>
        string(46) "http://www.aliexpress.com/item//944204198.html"
        ["productTitle"]=>
        string(118) "Hot selling! lady high canvas shoes summer & winter casual shoes sneakers for women Color block decoration top quality"
        ["validTime"]=>
        string(10) "2016-04-25"
        ["volume"]=>
        string(2) "18"
        ["evaluateScore"]=>
        string(3) "4.9"
        ["salePrice"]=>
        string(9) "US $32.40"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#9 (13) {
        ["lotNum"]=>
        int(1)
        ["packageType"]=>
        string(5) "piece"
        ["imageUrl"]=>
        string(144) "http://g03.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1N..tKXXXXXc3XXXXq6xXFXXXV/Slimming-font-b-shoes-b-font-women-fashion-leather-casual-font-b-shoes-b-font-women.jpg"
        ["30daysCommission"]=>
        string(8) "US $1.14"
        ["productId"]=>
        float(32426274938)
        ["discount"]=>
        string(2) "0%"
        ["originalPrice"]=>
        string(9) "US $27.04"
        ["productUrl"]=>
        string(48) "http://www.aliexpress.com/item//32426274938.html"
        ["productTitle"]=>
        string(101) "Free Shipping!Slimming sneakers for women, lady's Fitness Shoes Trendy Health Lady Beauty Swing Shoes"
        ["validTime"]=>
        string(10) "2016-04-11"
        ["volume"]=>
        string(2) "55"
        ["evaluateScore"]=>
        string(3) "4.8"
        ["salePrice"]=>
        string(9) "US $27.04"
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#10 (13) {
        ["lotNum"]=>
        int(1)
        ["packageType"]=>
        string(5) "piece"
        ["imageUrl"]=>
        string(160) "http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1t5a9KFXXXXcdXXXXq6xXFXXXN/Hot-Fashion-Women-Genuine-Leather-font-b-Shoes-b-font-Height-Increasing-Platform-Wedge-Sneakers-Low.jpg"
        ["30daysCommission"]=>
        string(8) "US $0.06"
        ["productId"]=>
        int(1717026606)
        ["discount"]=>
        string(2) "0%"
        ["originalPrice"]=>
        string(9) "US $49.58"
        ["productUrl"]=>
        string(47) "http://www.aliexpress.com/item//1717026606.html"
        ["productTitle"]=>
        string(123) "2014 Summer Cutout Shoes Velcro Elevator Color Block Decoration Sneaker Shoes Sport Shoes Casual High-Top Women's Cool Boot"
        ["validTime"]=>
        string(10) "2016-04-01"
        ["volume"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["evaluateScore"]=>
        string(3) "5.0"
        ["salePrice"]=>
        string(9) "US $49.58"
      }

    }
  }
  ["errorCode"]=>
  int(20010000)
}`
```

> this is the responce im getting i want to get the values in the base of keys using an loop for each 4 objects i tried many solution posted here but no one is working..

need help please reply!
thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific of what your desired output should be. Also let us know what you tried.

Comment: i want to get the value of "imageUrl" from each std class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$productsTitles = array();
foreach ($result->result->products as $product) {
    $productsTitles[] = $product->productTitle;
}
var_dump($productsTitles);
```

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ali\index.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />

Comment: foreach ($productListByKeyword['result']->producs as $product) {
    echo '<br />--------- ' . $product->productTitle . ' ----------';
    foreach ($product as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
    }
}  using this code but same error i mentioned above

Comment: `$productListByKeyword['result']->producs` you have a typo here: `products`

Comment: its not going in the loop error comes in first line and it does not enters in the first loop .. error is same  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array .. :( i appritiate your help maybe little more and we will have a solution ..

Comment: yes i did but it did not worked its the std class issue :(

Comment: Then it means you didn't put the entire response.. var dump the result and put it in the question

Comment: $productList = $ali->getListProduct(322, array('keywords'=>'man shoes', 'commissionRateFrom'=>0.5));

var_dump(get_object_vars($productList));   this is the code that show the result code that is mentioned in question

Comment: You are the guy man :) thank you very much really very good and im happy thank you soo much again :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you've got here a nice mixture of arrays and objects. Your outer array of 2 elements contains "results" what you care about and "errorCode".

First of all you need to loop through each result you have, then you need to find the desired field ("imageURL" according to the comment) and save it somewhere (or echo it, it doesn't matter).

I'll assume that your array of objects is called `$result`

```
$imageUrls = [];
if (isset($result["results"]) && isset($result["results"]->products) {
    foreach ($result["results"]->products as $productObject) {
         $imageUrls[] = $productObject->imageUrl;
    }
}

print_r($imageUrls); // This just dumps the output, you can do whatever else you want with it.
```